# PyAudio compilation error (Python.h: No such file or directory) on Linux

Tags: python, linux

```
(modulos-proyectos) josue@josue-OptiPlex-3010:~/Descargas/portaudio$ pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.14.tar.gz (47 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/pyaudio
      copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/pyaudio
      running build_ext
      building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/src/pyaudio
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/home/josue/Documentos/PythonUniversalModulos/modulos-proyectos/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
      In file included from src/pyaudio/device_api.c:1:
      src/pyaudio/device_api.h:7:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
          7 | #include "Python.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

He aprovado de Todo, la pagina oficial y nada

Comment: Did you try yo update `setuptools`?

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu or Debian-based systems, you can usually resolve this by installing the python3-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

For Red Hat, CentOS, or Fedora-based systems, you might need to install the python3-devel package:

```
sudo yum install python3-devel  # For CentOS/RHEL
```

or

```
sudo dnf install python3-devel  # For Fedora
```

Once you have installed the appropriate Python development headers, attempt to install pyaudio again using pip:

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Comment: This is how python headers are install in ubuntu.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before". We've had _hundreds_ of questions about pip failures because headers weren't installed; new instances should be closed as duplicative so we can consolidate on a single copy of the question with answers that are thoroughly vetted/edited/refined.